# How do i clean drawn path on canvas in android

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-canvas

i need some help on my android project.
i have a canvas and i fill it with some bitmap.
and i have a pointer that drawn a line on the canvas.
my problem is how to clean the line that i've drawn before?
what method should i call on canvas?
i've tried `Canvas.drawColor()`, `invalidate()` and that's not working.

and what is the function of `Canvas.drawColor()` and 
Please help me solve my problem.
thanks in advance

UPDATE!
if i made the code like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // fills the canvas with black
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

    canvas.drawPath(mPath, p);

    obaby.draw(canvas);
}
```

where i place `invalidate()` in my code?
and what code should i use if i want to clear the canvas using a button?

UPDATE!

i wrote my onDraw like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);  
    if(letsdraw){
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, p);
        obaby.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

and the method in reset button is like this:

```
public void rst(){
    letsdraw = false;
    invalidate();
    Log.v("tag", "this method called");

}
```

but no change in the canvas when i called the method.
did i wrote something wrong on the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your logic like this. Draw the line on the `Canvas` with some condition. Check if you want to draw the line, then draw the line.

Skeleton code -

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        if(needToDrawLine)
        {
            //draw the line
        }
        // Other drawing stuff
    }
```

Now just update your `needToDrawLine` variable and call `invalidate()`. You'll get your result. Let me know if it works.

**Update:**

`onDraw()` method will call everytime you call the `invalidate()`. So everyting inside the `onDraw()` will execute. The way is, you have to prevent it from drawing some of the part. You'll call `invalidate()` when you want to redraw the whole view, for example - button for clear the canvas.

- `canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);` this line clear your whole view to BLACK color.
- `canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);`  this line draw the bitmap at (0,0).
- `canvas.drawPath(mPath, p);` this line draw the path `mPath`.
- `obaby.draw(canvas);` some other object draw itself.

Now - for example you want to clear the screen, when button pressed. Just initialize a variable if it draw everything. And update the variable in button click.

```
public boolean drawEverything = true;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        if(drawEverything)
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, p);
            obaby.draw(canvas);
        }
    }

    public void buttonClicked( ... )
    {
        drawEverything = false;
    }
```

Comment: i still not understand what u said. i've post some code above. can you help me?

Comment: Shaiful, i add some update about my code. please check it out.

Answer (score -1):

Iam useing this errage the paint in my activity

```
            mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            mPath.reset();
            mView.invalidate();
```